# Link which is being clicked upon must stay active

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to make the link which is clicked on to be active. I have the following code down below and i tried different script codes to make the link active but it doesnt seem to work. What seems to be the problem?

```js
$("a").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

```css
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a.active {
    color: #23dbdb;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="Login.html" target="dest">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="buttonsstudent.html" target="dest">Result</a></li>
        <li><a href="card4.html" target="dest">Subjects</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutpage.html" target="dest">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: Why not use `a:active` but implement it with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

`a` tags has a default property of redirecting rather than staying on the same page. So when we click on `a`, that functionality will execute even before our code and hence our changes won't work as expected. That was the only part missing in your code, otherwise your code was working as expected. But, there will be more than one active classes at a time. So I made a few changes as below:

- Remove the `active` class from all the sibling links
- Add `active` class only for the corresponding link.

In this way, your code will work as a normal website is meant to work.

```js
$('a').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.red-links li  a').removeClass('active')
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a.active{
  color: #23dbdb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
     <ul class='red-links'>
        <li><a class="active" href="Login.html" target="dest">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="buttonsstudent.html" target="dest">Result</a></li>
        <li><a href="card4.html" target="dest">Subjects</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutpage.html" target="dest">About</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before adding the class get the `li a.active` and `removeClass` from it. Also you can do a validation to check if there exist an element `li a.active` before removing the class

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  $('li a.active').removeClass('active')
  $(this).addClass('active')

})
```

```css
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a.active {
  color: #23dbdb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>


  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="Login.html" target="dest">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="buttonsstudent.html" target="dest">Result</a></li>
    <li><a href="card4.html" target="dest">Subjects</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutpage.html" target="dest">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose a solution with *one line* of code jquery, in which the `active` class is removed from all `a`, excluding the current `a`, in which the `active` class is being added.

Method `not()` will exclude the current `a`.

```js
$("a").click(function () {
    $("a.active").removeClass("active").not($(this).addClass("active"));
});
```

```css
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a.active {
    color: #23dbdb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="Login.html" target="dest">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="buttonsstudent.html" target="dest">Result</a></li>
        <li><a href="card4.html" target="dest">Subjects</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutpage.html" target="dest">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might just need `:focus` for this functionality. No need of JavaScript / jQuery.

```css
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:active,   /* :active pseudo class instead of custom class 'active', just in case */
nav ul li a:focus {
  color: #23dbdb;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="Login.html" target="dest">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="buttonsstudent.html" target="dest">Result</a></li>
    <li><a href="card4.html" target="dest">Subjects</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutpage.html" target="dest">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```